# How to monitor NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, time, notifications, system

I Need to know if the user change the system time in the springboard settings.so my background program can be notified. According to doc, `NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification` is the one choice.
but I can't receiving anything by this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(handleSysTimeChanged:) 
                                             name:NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Where am I wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: i want your help, just i need to know weather this handleSysTimeChanged observer method did gets called when app is in background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your handler method must be implemented in the same class you add as observer and needs to look like this:

```
-(void) handleSysTimeChanged: (NSNotification*) notification
{
 // ...
}
```

Comment: I know ,but nslog  cann't print anyting in handleSysTimeChanged method.I am very certen  the notification never received.

Comment: have you tested on a device with iOS 4.0 or above?

Comment: i figure it out :UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification

Comment: How might it be possible to get the magnitude of the time-change?